# Cómo leer con tts los mensajes del toast

Tags: android, botón

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que al oprimir un botón muestra un mensaje Toast pero yo quiero que el text to speech lea el mensaje y no sé como se hace... Lo he hecho con un textview pero no me sirve así

el código de mi botón

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Toca dos veces para tomar foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

y el código del tts

```
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void TextToSpeechFunction() {
    //Aquí se supone que debe ir el toast pero no sé como
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        textToSpeech.speak(textholder, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
    else
        textToSpeech.speak(textholder, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    textToSpeech.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    Locale loc = new Locale ("spa", "ESP");
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        textToSpeech.setLanguage(loc);
        TextToSpeechFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**No se pueden leer los textos desde el `Toast` que generas**, lo que tienes que realizar es usar el mismo texto para `Toast` y el `TextToSpeech` :

```
String mensaje = "Hola Stackoverflow.com, este es mi mensaje";
...
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mensaje , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
...
textToSpeech.speak(mensaje, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```